# What would it mean if an acceleration vector didn't point to the exact center of a circle?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors

I thought it would mean that the circle is not a "circle" anymore and would be a different shape like an oval. But I'm also pretty sure that ovals have center pointing acceleration vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you know this but I'll reiterate it to make my point clearer. Just staying on a circular path (with constant velocity) will require you to constantly turn, this turning changes your velocity vector. A change in velocity over time is simply the definition of acceleration and hence there will always exist an acceleration towards the center of a circle.

Now lets say you want to *don't* want to travel along the circle with a constant velocity but instead you want your velocity to vary along the trajectory. In that case you will need to supply a *tangential* acceleration to help push you along your path. Then, at any given moment, you will have an acceleration that points in the radial direction *and* an acceleration that points tangent to the circle. Adding them up (vector sum!) will yield an overall net acceleration that does not point towards the center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the case of circular motion that has a constant speed, the acceleration must point toward the centre of the circle. What you could be referring to (correct me if I'm wrong) is if an object maintains a circular trajectory, but undergoes an acceleration in the speed. Take for instance the case of a merry-go-round that accelerates from rest (or comes to a stop). You have what is now called an azimuthal component to the acceleration.

I would reference you to this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_force